# Simplifying a repetitive Excel Formula / vlookup

Tags: excel, formula, lookup, vlookup

Basically, E5 changes from 1 - 100.
If it is 1 for example it goes to 'Paragons Level sheet and returns C1
If it is 2 for example it goes to 'Paragons Level sheet and returns C2
...

Is there a quicker way to do this, other than writing the formula out until E=100?

```
=IF(E5=1, 'Paragon levels sheet'!C1, IF(E5=2, 'Paragon levels sheet'!C2, IF(E5=3, 'Paragon levels sheet'!C3, IF(E5=4, 'Paragon levels sheet'!C4 IF(E5=5, 'Paragon levels sheet'!C5)))))
```

On my paragons level sheet it looks like this:
B Column, C Column
1, 5
2, 10
3, 20
4, 45
5, 100
... until B is 100

Would there be even a better formula, as E (1-100) is also reflected on paragons level sheet in B column, perhaps a vLookup to return the adjacent cell?
Example if E=4 look for 4 in paragon level sheet in column B and return the adjacent value 45.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `INDEX` function, as follows:

```
=INDEX('Paragon levels sheet'!C:C,E5)
```

Or you can do a `VLOOKUP` like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(E5,'Paragon levels sheet'!B:C,2,FALSE)
```